# Changing Windows 7 Desktop Background

Tags: windows-7, batch

i've been searching online for a batch solution to change the desktop background of Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits, and after several attempts, i could only get it to work once but never again...

I'm using this:

```
SET "str=C:\Users\Jorge\Dropbox\Photos\Wallpapers\1379362257639.jpg"
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d %str%
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

On the "Costumize" window after i run that, the new background appears there, but Desktop won't refresh... why?
Also, i confirmed registry key also changes to the path of the picture, and i've tried bmp extension.

The weird part is, if i run it multiple times, it finally randomly changes (to the correct image but randomly...) i don't know why?

Edit: It seems after 3rd/4th time running that same code, it finnaly changes.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i had no chance of accomplish this perfectly using only a batch file... as far my batch knowledge goes, so, i used vb.net to pinvoke the `SystemParametersInfo`  function like this:

```
Const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER As UInteger = &H14
Const SPIF_SENDCHANGE As UInteger = &H2

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "IMAGE_PATH", SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

Note: In this case, the image doesn't have to be bmp, i tested with jpg and it worked fine.
In my case there's no problem using vb.net to accomplish this, hope i helped somebody ;).

Answer (score 1):

Should

```
SET "str=C:\Users...
```

Be

```
SET str="C:\Users...
```

?

Comment: Well, that also works, i believe it is the same thing, the problem is, it doesn't always change at the first run of the batch file, i want to know why..

Comment: Relevant? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c5979d78-9732-41a7-8f7b-a9991e318b76/user32dllupdateperusersystemparameters-no-longer-works-windows-7-ultimate-x64?forum=w7itproui.

Comment: Well, i further searched and apparently i found out that this doesn't work properly in windows 7+... i don't really know how to use that API from a batch file, the example which was provided in there has the same effect on changing here..

Comment: As i see, the problem is only in refreshing the wallpaper, and as the RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters appears to not work properly, always needs multiple times (aproximately 4) to successfully refresh the desktop...

As i can't find anything right now that solves the problem, apparently this is being rouding up since [09](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d6dd7b3e-9bb3-4c9b-be1d-19e033c9014b/request-refresh-background?forum=w7itproui)